# error /node_modules/node-sass: Command failed with yarn

Tags: node.js, package, node-modules, yarnpkg, node-sass

I was write

> yarnn -i

to install all packages and I get this error:
I have to folder for packages

1- package-lock.json

2- package.json

```
[4/6] ⠐ node-sass
error C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Sultan Al-otaibi\\Desktop\\Noqat\\nogat\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@18.13.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Sultan Al-otaibi\Desktop\Noqat\nogat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
```

Also I thought the problem become cause there are some difference between the packages.
I wrote `npm outdated` to see the difference between the packages I get:

```
Package                         Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                                  Depended by
@material-ui/core                4.11.2   4.12.4  4.12.4  node_modules/@material-ui/core            nogat
@testing-library/jest-dom         4.2.4    4.2.4  5.16.5  node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom    nogat
@testing-library/react            9.5.0    9.5.0  13.4.0  node_modules/@testing-library/react       nogat
@testing-library/user-event       7.2.1    7.2.1  14.4.3  node_modules/@testing-library/user-event  nogat
dotenv                            8.2.0    8.6.0  16.0.3  node_modules/dotenv                       nogat
firebase                          8.2.1   8.10.1  9.15.0  node_modules/firebase                     nogat
history                           5.0.0    5.3.0   5.3.0  node_modules/history                      nogat
node-sass                        4.14.1   4.14.1   8.0.0  node_modules/node-sass                    nogat
react                           16.13.1  16.14.0  18.2.0  node_modules/react                        nogat
react-dom                       16.13.1  16.14.0  18.2.0  node_modules/react-dom                    nogat
react-modal                      3.11.2   3.16.1  3.16.1  node_modules/react-modal                  nogat
react-router-dom                  5.2.0    5.3.4   6.6.2  node_modules/react-router-dom             nogat
react-scripts                     3.4.1    3.4.1   5.0.1  node_modules/react-scripts                nogat
reactfire                    3.0.0-rc.0    3.0.0   4.2.2  node_modules/reactfire                    nogat
```